# What can be said about a set that is not open?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> For a metric space X.
>   A subset $U \subseteq  X$ is closed IFF for every sequence $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ with $x_{n} \in U$
>   for all n we also have $x \in U$.
>
> Attempt:

Supposing the "If" condition:

$\forall U \subseteq X : \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\rightarrow x$ with $x_{n} \in U$.

this implies $x \in U$ by the proposition.

We seek to show that $U\subseteq X$ is closed.
To do so, it suffice to show that the complement of $U$ (notated $U^{c}$) is open wrt X.

Suppose to the contrary that $U^{c}$ is not open.
By the negation of the definition of open set:

$\forall x \in U, \exists \epsilon >0: B_{\epsilon }\left ( x \right ) \nsubseteq  U$.

However, this is what is set out by my notes:

" Suppose $U^{c}$ is not open. 
Then, there exists $a \in U^{c}$ such that $\mathbf{\forall \epsilon >0}$ the intersection $B_{\epsilon }\left ( a \right ) \cap U$ is $\mathbf{ non-empty}$"

In particularly, I take offense with the bold-the emphasis on the non-empty intersection and "$\forall \epsilon$"

Based on my negation of my statement which looks fine, it conflicts with what is written in the notes.
If-based on the negation of the definition of open set-$B_{\epsilon }\left ( x \right ) \nsubseteq U$, it cannot be the case that the intersection of the open ball and U is non-empty.

Help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your negation of the definition of open set is wrong: it should say that there is an $x\in U$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$, $B_\epsilon(x)\nsubseteq U$.

Comment: Do you meant $U^{c}$ instead of U? 
I admit to that but how does it makes the intersection non-empty?
The open ball, regardless, is not contained in U. However can it be true that the intersection is non-empty?

Comment: May be with limit points, it's easier.

Comment: @Mathematicing: I used $U$ because you did, but yes, we’re both talking about $U^c$. The statement in your notes is correct: $B_\epsilon(a)\nsubseteq U^c$, so automatically $B_\epsilon(a)\cap U\ne\varnothing$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm going to ignore the swapping of "$U$" and "$U^c$", since the comments indicate you're aware of this.*

You are incorrectly negating a statement: the negation of "$\forall x\exists yP(x, y)$" is "$\exists x\forall y\neg P(x, y)$," not "$\forall x\exists y\neg P(x, y)$" as you have written. (The symbol "$\neg$" means "not".)

*In general, when you negate a statement of the form "$Q_1x_1Q_2x_2...Q_nx_n(\varphi)$," where each $Q_i$ is a quantifier (either "$\exists$" or "$\forall$"), you get "$P_1x_1P_2x_2...P_nx_n(\neg\varphi)$", where each $P_i$ is the* dual *of $Q_i$ ($P_i=\forall$ if $Q_i=\exists$, and $P_i=\exists$ if $Q_i=\forall$).*

So for example, $U^c$ is open iff $\forall x\in U^c\exists\epsilon>0[stuff]$. Negating this, we get that $U^c$ is *not* open iff $$\exists x\in U^c\forall \epsilon>0[not\mbox{ }stuff],$$ which is exactly the definition your notes have (except for the "nonempty intersection" bit, but see below).

For a conceptually easier example: consider the statement "For every natural number $m$, there is a strictly smaller natural number $n$", that is "$\forall m\exists n(n<m)$" (with quantifiers ranging over $\mathbb{N}$). This statement is clearly false, since there is a least natural number. That is, the reason it is false is $$\exists m\forall n(n\not<m).$$

---

As to the nonemptiness, note that "$B_\epsilon(a)\not\subseteq U^c$" means *exactly* that $B_\epsilon(a)\cap U\not=\emptyset$.

Comment: Can you make it explicitly as to how it "means exactly" that?

Comment: @Mathematicing What does "$X\not\subseteq Y$ mean? Well, it means $X$ is not a subset of $Y$ - that is, there is *some* point in $X$ which is *not* in $Y$. Well, that means $X\cap Y^c\not=\emptyset$. So "$B_\epsilon(a)\not\subseteq U^c$" means "$B_\epsilon(a)\cap U^{c^c}\not=\emptyset$", but the complement of the complement is the original set, so this just means "$B_\epsilon(a)\cap U\not=\emptyset$". By "exactly," I just meant that we don't have to think about what $B_\epsilon(a)$ and $U$ are, the equivalence between these two statements just comes from what $\subseteq$ and $^c$ mean.

Comment: I find it hard to understand the part where the open ball centered at a is not a subset of the complement of U means that the intersection of the open ball centered at a with U is an empty set. 
If the open ball centered at a is not a subset of the complement of U, then it must be in U, isn't it? But that definition, the intersection with U cannot be the empty set...

Comment: @Mathematicing No, that is incorrect. Here's a concrete example: take $A=\{1, 2\}$ versus $B=\{2, 3\}$ (in the natural numbers). Then $A$ is not a subset of the complement of $B$ - that is, $A\not\subseteq B^c$ - but also $A\not\subseteq B$. All you can say is that they *overlap* - that $A\cap B\not=\emptyset$. Does this make sense? This is purely a fact about sets: **if $X\not\subseteq Y^c$, then $X\cap Y\not=\emptyset$**. (It might be easier to think of the uncomplemented version first: do you understand why "$X\not\subseteq Y$" means "$X\cap Y^c\not=\emptyset$"?)

Comment: Thanks. I understand. It had occur to me that perhaps the open ball just isn't in 'both' sets. But I couldn't see it in the example of the theorem in the OP.

Comment: @Mathematicing Wait, the complement of $Y$ is a subset of $Y$? What?

Comment: Was confused by the notation I used and the ones you used. 
But yes, I see it now after giving myself a couple of examples then generalising it to symbolic notation.

Comment: Also, if you look at the OP, the notes states the intersection is non-empty, not "not non-empty".